# How to name variable to create box plot with Python

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am attempting to split `data2's` text into two groups and create a box plot. I am unable to name values for the graph plot without an error. What is wrong in the code?

```
f2 = open("data2.txt", "r")
data2 = f2.read()

with open('data2.txt') as f2:
    mental_disorders = f2.readlines()[0]

    
with open('data2.txt') as f2:
    healthy_persons = f2.readlines()[1]


value1 = [mental_disorders]
value2=[healthy_persons]
 
box_plot_data=[value1,value2]
plt.boxplot(box_plot_data,patch_artist=True,labels=['Mental','Healthy'])
plt.show()
```

Comment: Can you paste the contents of `box_plot_data`? Just a sample of 10-15 rows will help. Click edit and add the data as text at the bottom of your question

Comment: can you add the error message as well?